# How can I list the keys in the in-memory cache store on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.

How can I list the keys in the in-memory cache store on Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html) doesn't provide a way to access the store's keys directly (and neither does its parent class [ActiveSupport::Cache::Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html)).

Internally MemoryStore keeps everything in a Hash called `@data`, however, so you could monkey-patch or subclass it to get the keys, e.g.:

```
class InspectableMemoryStore < ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore
  def keys
    @data.keys
  end
end

ActionController::Base.cache_store = InspectableMemoryStore.new

Rails.cache.keys # => [ "foo", ... ]
```

This comes with the usual caveat, however: MemoryStore's internal implementation may change at any time and `@data` may disappear or be changed to something that doesn't `respond_to? :keys`. A smarter implementation might be to override the `write` and `delete` methods (since, as part of the public API, they're unlikely to change unexpectedly) to keep your own list of keys, e.g.:

```
class InspectableMemoryStore < ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore
  def write *args
    super

    @inspectable_keys[ args[0] ] = true
  end

  def delete *args
    super

    @inspectable_keys.delete args[0]
  end

  def keys
    @inspectable_keys.keys
  end
end
```

This is a very naive implementation, and of course keeping the keys in an additional structure takes up some memory, but you get the gist.

Comment: I just wanted to check the name of the keys. That will do the trick, big thanks!

Comment: What is the file where I set `ActionController::Base.cache_store = InspectableMemoryStore.new` ?

Comment: @Paul In your environment files, e.g. `config/environment/development.rb`. If it's inside the `Rails.application.configure do...end` block then it would just be `config.cache_store = InspectableMemoryStore.new`.

Comment: This isn't really monkey patching, is it?

Comment: @CppNoob I wrote, "you could monkey-patch *or* subclass it." The code above is an example of the latter.

Comment: This advise is nice, but unuseful, if you want to get unexpired keys.

Answer (score 104):

```
Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).keys
```

Comment: Doesn't work as of Rails 4.2 with a file store cache

Comment: Works with Rails 4.2.2 using redis-rails

Comment: Works with Rails 4.2 with a memorystore cache

Comment: `Rails.cache.instance_variable_get("@data")` works for me in Rails 4 with Dalli :)

Comment: Works with Rails 5.2 with a memorystore cache

Comment: If you're using the redis gem, you can use the following in Rails 6 ```Rails.cache.redis.keys```

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 6, with Redis used as a cache store

```
Rails.cache.redis.keys
```

Comment: Downvoted because this specifically shows the incorrect answer (using Redis) but is shown above all the correct answers for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to access the keys dynamically, an easier approach is locating the directory where the cache is stored. A file is created for each entry.

In my case this was at "APP_ROOT/tmp/cache", but you can easily locate it by going to rails console and typing

```
1.8.7 :030 >   Rails.cache.clear
 => ["path_to_rails_app/tmp/cache/6D5"]
```

Comment: But your solution worked only when file cache.if I use memcached as backend cache, this doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Fetch all keys:

```rb
Rails.cache.data.keys
```

Read the specific key

```rb
Rails.cache.read("cache_key")
```

Delete one key from keys:

```rb
Rails.cache.delete("cache_key")
```

Flush out the keys

```rb
Rails.cache.clear
```